# Visual Studio XAML Hot Reload on Android causes "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, hot-reload

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition Version 17.3.4 to develop a Xamarin app for Android.

When I start the app in debug mode on the emulator or a physical device it runs fine, but as soon as I make an edit in the XAML file and hot reload kicks in, Android starts reporting

> [Choreographer] Skipped x frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

and then goes extremely slow. To recover, I have to stop the app and restart the debug session.

Anybody know how I can solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement async tasks in your code using async-await Task.Run.

For more details, you can refer to the following docs:
[Task.Run Method | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0a)

Answer (score 0):

I had issues on both iOS and Android simulators/emulators as well as on devices while running on debug mode with XAML hot reload turned on. I got it resolved by loading Full page than changes thru VS Mac preferences.

[image]